# What is the property blockInd

Tags: meteor, d3.js, reactjs, webcola

I am working on a project with d3 and cola, and when i try to update my svg, I sometimes get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'blockInd' of undefined

I dont understand where this error is coming from and i dont know what is this property. Can someone point me where should I look?

Comment: did you try "pause on exception"?

Comment: Well i dont know where i should put a break point so how can i pause on exception

Comment: In firefox there is option in devtools settings. In chrome there is button for this in sources tab in devtools

Comment: so this is where i stopped `swapBlock.blockInd = b.blockInd;` the b is an int 69

Comment: The error "Cannot set property 'blockInd' of undefined" indicates that you are attempting to set a property (i.e. blockInd) on a object (i.e. swapBlock) that is undefined. Somewhere in code, you missed assigning a value to swapBlock.

Comment: The problem is that this is not my code, but the cola library. More precisely vpsc.ts file